# Why is the answer specifically OH-?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution

> When solid **A** is added to water, some dissolves to form a colourless solution.
>
> When phenolphthalein is added to this mixture, it turns pink.
>
> When dilute hydrochloric acid is added to the mixture, the temperature increases and a colourless solution forms, but no gas is given off.
>
> (i) Identify, by name or formula, the anion present in **A**.

I believe the answer could be either $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{O^2-}$. What am missing?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: There are many possible answers, not just $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{O^{2-}}$.

Answer (score 6):

If you attempt to answer this question in the most literal way possible then it can only be a hydroxide. Note that the question says *dissolved* and not *reacted.* Anything that dissolves in water to create an alkaline solution and does not contain hydroxide ions *must* have reacted in some way. That specifically applies to oxide ions which are not stable in aquaeous solution.

Of course, if you remove the *must not react* constraint I just added by reading the question extremely literally, then you can have a lot more compounds, e.g. acetates.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was thinking too..the suttle difference of "dissolved" and "reacted"..Thanks alot for making it clearer..